AWS ENA TX packet over DPDK
I have two machines: sender and receiver. Both machines are in different VPC but they are peered.
While ports are binded to kernel, I am able to ping from sender to receiver machine.
On receiver machine, when I start l2fwd application, I receive the packets successfullly.
But when I configure the port with DPDK on sender machine. The packet is not received on sender machine.

The packet I built for transmission contains eth and ip headers with proper values for dst mac and dst IP.
The packets are sent successfully, and rte_eth_tx_burst returns success.
In the monitoring tab, I can't see the packets sent through in Outbound traffic.

In short, when the sender machine port is binded with the kernel. I can send packets to the receiver but when configured with DPDK, I cannot send packets (Even though packets contain proper Ethernet and IP header).
